# facebook redirect after app authentication

Tags: facebook, events, authorization

I am developing a functionality to allow facebook users to  register in our web application.
The approach is:

1. We will create one app on facebook
2. Facebook authentication plugin (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) will be used in our registration page.
3. When user clicks on facebook button, facebook login page and then app authorization page are shown.
4. One user allows/disallows facebook app, user will be redirected to a particular page within our website.

I am not able to find a proper even handler to capture app authorization (allow/disallow event) to redirect user. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the JS SDK:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.status=="connected") {
        // authorized the app
    } else {
        // did not authorized the app
    }
}, {
    perms: 'email'
});
```

Trigger a call to this function when the user click the button.

```
<div class="fb-login-button">Login</div>
```